# Removing all controls from a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to remove all the controls (zoom, map type drop down, and street view) from my map.

There's a method

```
map.removeControl(GControl)
```

but I haven't been able to successfully remove any default ones that I hadn't added myself.

Any tips on remove/clearing all controls from the map?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have you tried this:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#DisablingDefaults

```
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
       myOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, disableDefaultUI: true is the one.

Comment: is there no way to hide the ui controls after the map is rendered? I am not looking forward to make a new Map object when I want to enable/disable these controls.

Comment: @DanielvanDommele try this map.setOptions({disableDefaultUI:true});
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980654/is-there-a-way-to-hide-all-the-ui-controls-of-google-map-after-initialised/48980867#48980867

Answer (score 24):

You may see this: [google map api by w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_controls.asp)

As you see in the link, this disables all controls:

```
var mapOptions = {disableDefaultUI: true}
```

and the bellow is the options to make them enabled or disabled.

```
var mapOptions = {
  panControl: true,
  zoomControl: true,
  mapTypeControl: true,
  scaleControl: true,
  streetViewControl: true,
  overviewMapControl: true,
  rotateControl: true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**just  disableDefaultUI: true**

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can create a copy of the GMapUIOptions object and then remove the items you don't want to appear.

From http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls.html#MapUIOptions

"Using the GMapUIOptions Object

The GMapUIOptions object contains a set of properties that specify control placement and UI behavior, which you may modify. For a full set of properties, see the GMapUIOptions reference.
Rather than write a GMapUIOptions structure from scratch, you may wish to prepopulate it with the UI behavior available on Google Maps. To do so, use the GMap2.getDefaultUI() method. Once populated, you can modify individual properties to tweak the behavior and initialize the map's UI controls using the GMap2.setUI() method.
The following code retrieves the default UI on a "large" map, removes the GScaleControl and resets the map to use the modified UI.

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    { size: new GSize(400,150) } );
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(41.897997,-87.790203), 11);
var customUI = map.getDefaultUI();
customUI.controls.scalecontrol = false;
map.setUI(customUI);
```

"

Comment: I'm using V3, it seems getDefaultUI is no longer used. You can specify which options to use in the MapOptions, but i don't see a way to select none.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad - they've depreceated the V2 API now, haven't they. I think the secret may lie in how you call up an instance of a google map: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#ControlModification