# hide google map v2 controls

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i know that in google map v3 it was already answered here:
[Removing all controls from a google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302991/removing-all-controls-from-a-google-map)

my question is on V2.
how to remove the controls from google map v2 (Map, Satellite, Terrain)
such as only the map will be shown as defined in setMapType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that the "setUIToDefault" method is not called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example: Simple Map</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=AIzaSyD4iE2xVSpkLLOXoyqT-RuPwURN3ddScAI"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
        //map.setUIToDefault();
      }
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```