# Is there a way to show/hide all the UI controls from google map after initialised?

Tags: javascript, maps

There is an option on Google Maps disableDefaultUI set to false before loading google Maps.

```js
function initMap(){ 
var mapVar = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
  }
```

Is there any way to hide all the controls using my mapVar variable once the map is rendered?

[Removing all controls from a google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302991/removing-all-controls-from-a-google-map) - This question is about hiding the map on load.

Comment: Why not just use CSS to target the map components (with maximum specificity)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing all controls from a google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302991/removing-all-controls-from-a-google-map)

Comment: @ObsidianAge that seems like a very tedious way to do it versus what the API says to do, but it could work

Comment: @ObsidianAge I was referring the documentation, the API has control on each property. I was looking for something like mapVar.disableDefaultUI = true. Unfortunately i don't find anything as such

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a method to hide controls dynamically.

```js
mapVar.setOptions({disableDefaultUI:true});
```

In case if we want to hide a single option mapVar.setOptions({zoomControl:false});

Comment: If you want to close keyboard and mouse options too then use `keyboardShortcuts: false` and `draggable: false` with `disableDefaultUI:true`